# Ionic v1 error run Android (Error gulp and Sass)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ionic-framework, sass, gulp

I have a problem when run Android ionic v1, I stuck to solve this problem, please anyone help me to solve this problem.

This is error I get in my Command Prompt when execute 'ionic cordova run android'.

> [12:04:07] Cannot load gulp: AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task
>   function must be specified [12:04:07] Cannot run sass task: missing in
>   gulpfile.js

Please anyone help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you have gulp installed locally?

Answer (score 0):

Your gulp task sass is missing. Check your gulpfile if it has the task `sass` in it should be something like this:

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('path/to/sass)
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});
```